# Merge downscaled view's image with images from subviews remaining original size

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I saw on Stackoverflow o dozen of similar questions.

Even though, none of them helped. I have an app where I make a photo and then add some images over this photo. Then I need to save taken photo with images which I have put on it. Here is how my structure looks like:

[image]

As you can see I have a `Photo Scroll View` with `Photo View` inside. Each added sticker goes inside `Photo Scroll View` as a subview.

Now, how can I merge all images from `Photo Scroll View` into a single image. So far I have managed to save it with size of a screen which is definitely too small.

```
func saveImage(_ sender: Any) {

    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(photoScrollView.frame.size)
    photoScrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

}
```

Also, i tried it by creating a snapshot. In this case the image contained just a white screen and nothing else(and it is not a background color of any view).

```
func saveImage(_ sender: Any) {

    let snapShot:UIView = self.photoScrollView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.photoScrollView.bounds.size)
    snapShot.drawHierarchy(in: self.photoScrollView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

}
```

Could anyone help me there?

Comment: Using the first try, call `photoScrollView.draw(rect: photoScrollView.frame)`

Comment: @gkchristopher I replaced `photoScrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)` with `photoScrollView.draw(rect: photoScrollView.frame)`. Didn't help. Result is just a white image while `photoScrollView` background is green.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various of approaches I found a solution by wrapping `Photo View` inside a simple `UIView` (I call it `placeholderView`). All added images I put inside `placeholderView` as subviews so they are on same level as `photoView`.

As a result I have structure: `Photo Scroll View -> placeholderView-> ALL_OTHER_SUBVIEWS`. `ALL_OTHER_SUBVIEWS` consist of background photo and added images on top of it.

And the code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(_ sender: Any) {

    //Create the UIImage
    let zoomVal = photoScrollView.zoomScale
    photoScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(placeholderView.frame.size)
    placeholderView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    photoScrollView.zoomScale = zoomVal
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

}
```